# ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.BaseModelListener

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-7, bnd, bndtools

I wrote a Liferay module:

```
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    service = ModelListener.class
)
public class TopMessageListener extends BaseModelListener<JournalArticle> {
    // Do stuff
}
```

with this `bnd.bnd`:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: fr.free.nrw.impl
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Liferay-Require-SchemaVersion: 1.0.0
Import-Package: !org.apache.avalon.framework.logger, !org.apache.log \
  *
```

And this in my `build.gradle` (among other things):

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.6.0"
compileInclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'
```

It compiles fine, but deployment fails:

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.BaseModelListener cannot be found by fr.free.nrw.impl_1.0.0
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

The error disappears if I replace `compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal"` with `compileInclude group: "com.liferay.portal"`, but I am sure it is not the correct way to do things. How to correctly fix the `ClassNotFoundException` above?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this dependency 
compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the httpcomponents line into two lines, one `compileOnly` and one `runtime`:

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.6.0"

compileOnly group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'
runtime group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'
```

That solved the problem for me.